# PowerShell REST inner body

Tags: rest, powershell

I can't seem to figure out how to make an inner body for a post request.

For instance this is how it looks if I were to do it in fidder.

```
{
 "test" : 
 [ 
  {
  "test1" : null,
  "test2" : null
  }
 ]
}
```

For a normal body I would just do this.  I would just create an array and add the params.  E.g

```
 $body @{};
 $body.add("test1", null);
 $body.add("test2", null);
```

So I am not sure how to accomplish this with an inner body. I've tried the following and it doesn't work.

```
 $innerBody = @{};
 $innerBody.add("test1", null);
 $innerBody.add("test2", null);

 $body = @{};
 $body.add("test", $innerBody);
```

When i try that, i get some odd "can not deserialized instance.

Any ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$body = 
@{

    test = @(
        @{ 
            test1 = $null
            test2 = $null
        }
    )


}

$body | ConvertTo-Json
```

test1 and test2 are elements of a hashtable within an array. so there can be more than one hashtable

using "add"

```
    $body = @{}
    $innerbody = @(@{test1 = $null; test2 = $null })
    $body.Add('test',$innerbody)
    $body | ConvertTo-Json
```

Comment: So you can't do this any way using .add?

Comment: thought the first method wud be easier to pass to the rest endpoint but anyway see the edited answer for the "add method"

Comment: Thanks I appreciate your help!